# regex pattern matching in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a pattern for a string in Java. The format of the string will be like this.

"INSERT %ABC% %DEF%"

I want to be able to take strings ABC and DEF between the two set of '%'

```
public void parseInput(String input){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("?: .* %(.*)%)*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    String s1 = m.group(1);
    String s2 = m.group(2);
}
```

I've played around so far, and continue to get syntax errors. In this case, this has been my most recent attempt, having gotten a dangling meta character error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `.find()` method which will keep on going through your string and yielding what it finds:

```
    String str = "INSERT %ABC% %DEF%";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%(.*?)%");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Yields:

> ABC
>
> DEF

EDIT: Just as an FYI, having a pattern like so: `%(.*)%`, will make your regular expression *greedy*, meaning that it will stop matching once it finds the *last* `%` (thus yielding `ABC% %DEF`). Adding the `?` operator after the `*` operator (as per my example) will make your pattern *non greedy*, and it will stop at the first `%` it finds.

Comment: Ahh thank you! That works quite well. Also didn't know about the difference between greedy and non greedy regular expressions

Comment: @Nopiforyou: You're welcome. Greediness is something you need to keep an eye out when using the `*` and `+` operators.